# Discrete Laplacian

Tags: markov-process, heat-equation, graph-laplacian

I have the following question and I can't figure out how to do the proof. Could you give me some hints in both directions of the equivalence?

Suppose $A$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{Z}^d$. Then $\bar{A} = A \cup \partial A $ where $\partial A$ is the outer boundary defined by $ \partial A = \{y \in A^c : |x - y| = 1 $ for some $ x \in A\}$. We call $ \{x; y\} $ an edge of $ \bar{A} $ if $ x, y \in \bar{A}, |x - y| = 1 $ and at least one of $ x, y $ is in $ A $. If $ F : \bar{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a function, we define its energy by
\begin{equation*}
E(f) = \sum_{\{x,y\} \text{ edge of } \bar{A}} (f(x) - f(y))^2.
\end{equation*}
For any $ F : \partial A \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, define $ E(F) $ to be the infimum of $ E(f) $ where the infimum is over all $ f $ on $ \bar{A} $ that agree with $ F $ on $ \partial A $. Show that if $ f $ agrees with $ F $ on $ \partial A $, then $ E(f) = E(F) $ if and only if $ f $ is harmonic in $ A $.

Update: I believe this can be proved using the Discrete Divergence Theorem, but I still don't know how.

Comment: You should probably look up the notion of a (discrete) Dirichlet form.

Comment: Ultimately the proof is just to compute the gradient and set it equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have computed the gradient and set it to zero but I still got stuck.